# what is the reason ..we say can't? intead of can not

Tags: contractions

Numerous exceptions r there in English grammar ,why it is so?
Like I m still confused between 
India HAS/HAVE won the match?

Comment: Try to ask only one question in a post.

Comment: I find it funny that OP contracts 'are' to 'r' while asking why we have contractions.

Comment: Hi Raman. Please read [this page](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) to know what kind of questions you can ask here. This question is off-topic for many, many reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Contracting two often used words to one word is a phenomenon you can find in almost all languages of the world. We think with a certain speed and the speed of thinking and speaking should correspond. That's why shortenings in every possible form are common in all languages.